# Why setInterval logs exponentially for every re-render?

Tags: reactjs

```
import { useState } from "react";
function ParentComp(props){
  console.log("rendering parent");
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({ firstName: "First" });  
  setInterval(() => {
    setPerson({ firstName: "Second" });
  }, 6000);
  return (
    <>     
      <ChildComp name={person.firstName} />
    </>
  );
}
function ChildComp({ name }){
  console.log("Rendering child");
  return <div>{name}</div>;
}
export default ParentComp;
```

[image: console log , logs exponentionally]

I expect the console log to log consecutively, but I found that it is re-rendering the parent and child components exponentially like 2times, 4times, 8 times ..so on. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becase you are calling `setInterval` in your component and not in `useEffect` there is new interval every rerender, because all that code is called every render.

If you want to have setInterval in react, you need to use it in useEffect and in cleanup function of useEffect, you need to remove this interval:

```
function ParentComp(props){
  console.log("rendering parent");
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({ firstName: "First" });
  var i = 0;
  React.useEffect(()=>{
 const interval =   setInterval(() => {
    setPerson({ firstName: "Second" });
  }, 6000);
    return ()=>clearInterval(interval);
  },[])

  return (
    <>
      {person.firstName}
      <ChildComp name={person.firstName} />
    </>
  );
}
function ChildComp({ name }){
  console.log("Rendering child");
  return <div>{name}</div>;
}
export default ParentComp;
```

Comment: Even without cleanup, it is working.

Comment: nice, but be careful... without cleanup, everytime you rerender parent of this component, you will be facing the same issue as before